# Почему SQLite в Python не возвращает ничего, а в DB Browser-е вовращает?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Проблема заключается в том, что запрос дает ответа в SQLite DB Browser-е, а в питоне ничего не возвращает. Коды разместил ниже. Помогите понять, в чем проблема?

**Вот код в Питоне**

```
    def count_upd():
    cur.execute("""SELECT Количество FROM Распределение WHERE ID_Продукт=1 AND ID_Филиал=1;""").fetchone()

    print(tuple(cur))
```

Не помогло менять fetchone() - fetchall(). Еще попробовал присвоить данные из запроса в отдельные объекты типов tuple() и list(), но всё же не выводятся значения.
Хочу отметить, что используя тот-же код из остальных таблиц всё выводится нормально.

**Вот результат выполнения этого-же запроса в SQlite браузере:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Структура таблицы:**
**1)**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Структура таблицы:**
**2)**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ничего не вернуть не могло, т.к. там `print`, убедитесь, что тот код на питоне выполнялся

Comment: Как минимум потому, что fetchone возвращает значение, а вы это значение никуда не сохранили и просто выкинули

Comment: Спасибо за ответы и оказывается получить кортеж прямо из cursor()-а невозможно.

Answer (score 0):

Вы сделали запрос но никуда не записали ответ.

```
cursor.execute(f'''ЗАПРОС''')
results = cursor.fetchall()
```